# Time dilation of accelerating object vs caught by gravity well

Tags: acceleration, time-dilation

Suppose an object got caught by the immerse gravitational force but at the same time it has zero net force acting on it like suspending above the surface of a planet, not siting on the surface where it experiences weight. How do time flow for this object or have I misunderstood the concept of time dilation? Please provide illustrations to support your answer I really really need it, thanks and I don't speak maths.

Imagine a pair of twin named Alice and Bob, Alice took a return trip to a nearby star at close to speed of light. At the moment when Alice took off and leave the solar system Earth suddenly becomes very massive due to then unknown mechanism so that upon their happy reunion it is possible for both Alice and Bob to age at the same rate... Wouldn't that be puzzling? (I'm referring to their aging not the mechanism. )

Comment: @Dan Yand: I meant to say the planet exert a strong gravitational force on the object however since I want my object to counter that force so that there is zero resultant force acting on it.

Comment: Yes maybe it's orbit is tidal locked, I just don't want it to have any acceleration.

Comment: Please note that time dilation, difference in time measured by two observers, in two different  frames cannot appear in a single inertial frame. Look at the twin paradox http://look%20at%20https//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox

Comment: @anna v: from Bob frame of ref, Alice is moving at close to speed of light even though Bob now is trying super hard to maintain free fall to counter the sudden change of Earth gravitational pull exerting on him. Trying to understand difference between Alice's time and Bob's time.

Comment: they are two different  frames , accelerated frames  with respect to each other are not inertial frames, and then one has to use the algebra of special relativity not hand wave Bobs and Alices